# Javascript CLI to boot iOS simulators, install project, extract data, and merge into JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, ios, macos

I'm a DIY "dev" - so I really create things that I need or think they'll end up helping others.

I wrote this Swift Package so the iOS community could get device bezel radius' to help with UI design since it's not a value easily available.

In order to extract the data though it needs to run on a macOS system, with Xcode installed, iterating through every iOS and iPadOS simulator.

This Javascript code was supposed to help automate that, and make it so I'd be able to drop in the new device identifiers into a text file, let the script run, extract the data, merge it into a new JSON file (for the main Swift package), and then move the identifiers to the completed or problematic lists - so they don't get re-run.

I know it's not the best code but hoping that some whizzes and whizzettes could review it and help improve it!

There is the repo here if it makes it easier too: https://github.com/markbattistella/BezelKit

```js
// MARK: - modules

// Import the 'fs' module, which provides an interface for file system operations.
const fs = require('fs');

// Import the 'fs.promises' module, an extension of 'fs' that offers promise-based file system methods.
const fsp = require('fs').promises;

// Import the 'readline' module for creating interactive command-line interfaces by reading input streams.
const readline = require('readline');

// Import the 'execSync' function from the 'child_process' module to execute shell commands synchronously.
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

// Import the 'path' module to work with file and directory paths in a platform-independent manner.
const path = require('path');


const LOGGING = (() => {

  // Directory for storing logs
  const LOG_DIR = 'logs';

  // File path for the main log file
  const LOG_FILE = path.join(LOG_DIR, '_console.log');

  // Create the log directory if it doesn't exist
  if (!fs.existsSync(LOG_DIR)) {
    fs.mkdirSync(LOG_DIR, { recursive: true });
  }

  // Archive the existing log file if it exists
  if (fs.existsSync(LOG_FILE)) {
    const date = new Date().toISOString().replace(/[:.]/g, '-');
    const archiveLogName = `console_${date}.log`;
    const destination = path.join(LOG_DIR, archiveLogName);
    fs.renameSync(LOG_FILE, destination);
  }

  /**
   * Custom logger function.
   *
   * @param {...any} args - Arguments to be logged.
   */
  const customLogger = (...args) => {
    // Check if debug mode is enabled before logging
    if (!VARIABLES.debug) return;

    // Call the original console.log
    console._log(...args);

    // Create log entry with a human-readable timestamp
    const entry = `[${getHumanReadableTimestamp()}] ` + args.join(' ') + '\n';
    fs.appendFile(LOG_FILE, entry, err => {
      if (err) {
        console._log('Failed to write to log:', err);
      }
    });
  };

  /**
   * Get a human-readable timestamp.
   *
   * @returns {string} Human-readable timestamp.
   */
  const getHumanReadableTimestamp = () => {
    const date = new Date();
    const options = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: '2-digit',
      day: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
      second: '2-digit',
      hour12: true
    };
    return date.toLocaleString(undefined, options);
  };

  // Store the original console.log as console._log
  console._log = console.log;

  // Replace console.log with the custom logger
  console.log = customLogger;
})();

const DEFAULTS = {

  /**
   * The CSV file which contains all the device models and internal identifiers.
   * @type {string}
   */
  deviceCsv: './Simulators/apple-device-database.csv',

  /**
   * The file containing the list of target simulators from which to gather bezel data.
   * @type {string}
   */
  targetSims: './Simulators/target-simulators.txt',

  /**
   * The file containing the list of simulators from which bezel data has already been extracted.
   * This is used for filtering to prevent overloading the script's runtime.
   * @type {string}
   */
  completedSims: './Simulators/completed-simulators.txt',

  /**
   * The file containing the list of simulator identifiers that have no runtime installed,
   * but have not been run previously. Used to identify new devices without runtimes.
   * @type {string}
   */
  problematicSims: './Simulators/problematic-simulators.txt',

  /**
   * The path to the Xcode project used to extract bezel data.
   * @type {string}
   */
  projectPath: './FetchBezel/FetchBezel.xcodeproj',

  /**
   * The name of the Xcode scheme to use for extracting bezel data.
   * @type {string}
   */
  schemeName: 'FetchBezel',

  /**
   * The bundle identifier of the Xcode project where bezel data can be extracted.
   * @type {string}
   */
  bundleID: 'com.mb.FetchBezel',

  /**
   * The location to save the output merged JSON data for next run.
   * @type {string}
   */
  mergedOutputFilePath: './cache.json',

  /**
   * The location to save the output merged JSON data for use in the Package.
   * @type {string}
   */
  bezelKitResources: '../Sources/BezelKit/Resources/bezel.min.json',

  /**
   * Whether to generate a log file for reporting or not.
   * @type {boolean}
   */
  debug: true
};

const ARGS = ((argv) => {

  /**
   * Parses command-line arguments into an object.
   *
   * @param {string[]} argv - Array of command-line arguments.
   * @returns {Object} Parsed arguments as key-value pairs.
   */
  const args = {};

  // Iterate through command-line arguments starting from the third element
  // (excluding 'node' and script filename)
  for (const arg of argv.slice(2)) {
    let [argName, argValue] = arg.split('=');

    // Remove leading dashes from the argument name
    argName = argName.replace(/^-+/, '');

    if (argValue) {
      // Convert argValue to a number if it's a numeric string, otherwise
      // keep it as a string
      argValue = isNaN(argValue) ? argValue : parseFloat(argValue);
    } else {
      // If no value provided, consider it as a boolean flag
      argValue = true;
    }

    // Store the argument and its value in the args object
    args[argName] = argValue;
  }

  return args;
})(process.argv);


/**
 * Assigns a value or a default value based on the condition.
 *
 * @param {*} value - The value to assign or evaluate.
 * @param {*} defaultValue - The default value to use if the condition is met.
 * @returns {*} The assigned value or the default value.
 */
const assignOrDefault = (value, defaultValue) => (
  value === undefined || value === true ? defaultValue : value
);

/**
 * Reads a file and returns a set of unique non-empty lines from it.
 *
 * @param {string} file - The path to the file to read.
 * @returns {Promise<Set<string>>} A Promise that resolves with a Set of unique non-empty lines from the file.
 */
const getUniqueLinesFromFile = async (file) => {
  try {
    // Check if the file exists and is accessible
    await fsp.access(file, fs.constants.F_OK);

    // Create a read stream for the file
    const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file, 'utf8');

    // Create a readline interface to read lines from the stream
    const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: fileStream, crlfDelay: Infinity });

    // Set to store unique non-empty lines
    const uniqueLines = new Set();

    // Iterate through each line and add non-empty lines to the set
    for await (const line of rl) {
      if (line.trim() !== '') {
        uniqueLines.add(line);
      }
    }

    return uniqueLines;
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors by displaying an error message and exiting the process
    console.error(`[x] ERROR: issue with file: ${file}.`);
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

/**
 * Executes a shell command and returns its output.
 *
 * @param {string} command - The shell command to execute.
 * @returns {string} The output of the executed command.
 * @throws {Error} If there's an issue executing the command.
 */
const executeCommand = (command) => {
  try {
    // Execute the shell command and capture its output as a string
    return execSync(command, { encoding: 'utf8' });
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors by displaying an error message and rethrowing the error
    console.error(`[x] ERROR: executing command: ${command}.`);
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
    throw error;
  }
};

/**
 * Executes a shell command and attempts to parse its output as JSON.
 *
 * @param {string} command - The shell command to execute.
 * @returns {Object} Parsed JSON data from the executed command.
 * @throws {Error} If there's an issue executing the command or parsing JSON.
 */
const getSimulatorData = (command) => {
  // Execute the shell command and capture its output as a string
  const output = executeCommand(command);

  try {
    // Attempt to parse the output as JSON and return the parsed data
    return JSON.parse(output);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle errors by displaying an error message and exiting the process
    console.error(`[x] ERROR: parsing JSON from command: ${command}.`);
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

/**
 * Retrieves information about the installed simulators using xcrun simctl.
 *
 * @returns {Object[]} An array of objects representing the installed simulators.
 */
const getInstalledSimulators = () => {
  // Use the getSimulatorData function to execute the command and parse JSON
  return getSimulatorData('xcrun simctl list devices -j').devices;
};

/**
 * Retrieves information about the installed simulators runtimes using xcrun simctl.
 *
 * @returns {Object[]} An array of objects representing the installed simulator runtimes, sorted by version.
 */
const getInstalledRuntimes = () => {
  // Use the getSimulatorData function to execute the command and parse JSON
  const runtimes = getSimulatorData('xcrun simctl list runtimes -j').runtimes;

  // Sort the runtimes array by version in descending order
  runtimes.sort((a, b) => {
    const versionA = parseFloat(a.version);
    const versionB = parseFloat(b.version);
    return versionB - versionA;
  });

  return runtimes;
};

/**
 * Appends a unique data item to a file if it doesn't already exist.
 *
 * @param {string} data - The data item to append.
 * @param {string} filePath - The path to the file.
 */
const append = async (data, filePath) => {
  try {
    // Get unique lines from the file
    const uniqueLines = await getUniqueLinesFromFile(filePath);

    // Append the data item if it's not already present
    if (!uniqueLines.has(data)) {
      await fsp.appendFile(filePath, `\n${data}`, 'utf-8');
      uniqueLines.add(data);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`[x] ERROR: appending data to file: ${data}`);
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

/**
 * Removes a data item from a file if it exists.
 *
 * @param {string} data - The data item to remove.
 * @param {string} filePath - The path to the file.
 */
const remove = async (data, filePath) => {
  try {
    // Get unique lines from the file
    const uniqueLines = await getUniqueLinesFromFile(filePath);

    // Remove the data item if it exists
    if (uniqueLines.has(data)) {
      uniqueLines.delete(data);
      const updatedContent = [...uniqueLines].join('\n');
      await fsp.writeFile(filePath, updatedContent, 'utf-8');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`[x] ERROR: removing data from file: ${data}`);
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
  }
};

/**
 * Moves a data item from one file to another.
 *
 * @param {string} data - The data item to move.
 * @param {string} fromFile - The source file path.
 * @param {string} toFile - The destination file path.
 */
const moveData = async (data, fromFile, toFile) => {
  // Append the data to the destination file and remove from the source file
  await append(data, toFile);
  await remove(data, fromFile);
};

/**
 * Asynchronously sorts the lines of a text file and writes the sorted content to a new file named 'sorted.txt'.
 * 
 * @param {string} filePath - The path to the text file that will be sorted.
 * @throws Will throw an error if reading from the file or writing to the file fails.
 */
const sortFile = async (filePath) => {
  try {
    // Read the file into a string
    const data = await fsp.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');

    // Split the string into lines
    const lines = data.split('\n');

    // Sort the lines
    const sortedLines = lines.sort();

    // Join the sorted lines back into a string
    const sortedData = sortedLines.join('\n');

    // Write the sorted string back to a file
    await fsp.writeFile(filePath, sortedData, 'utf8');

    console.log('[i] INFO: File sorted successfully.');
    console.log(`    ↳ ${filePath}`);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('[x] Error: File sorting failed.');
    console.error(`    ↳ ${filePath}`);
  }
};

/**
 * Retrieves the value of a specific setting from a string of build settings.
 *
 * @param {string} settings - The build settings as a string.
 * @param {string} key - The key of the setting to retrieve the value for.
 * @returns {string|null} The value of the specified setting, or null if not found.
 */
const getSettingValue = (settings, key) => {
  // Find the line containing the key and extract the value
  const settingLine = settings.split('\n').find(line => line.includes(key));
  return settingLine ? settingLine.split('=')[1].trim() : null;
};

/**
 * Adds a delay to an asynchronous function using a Promise.
 *
 * @param {number} ms - The delay time in milliseconds.
 * @returns {Promise<void>} A Promise that resolves after the specified delay.
 */
const delay = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const isEmptyObject = (obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).length === 0 && obj.constructor === Object;
};


/**
 * Initializes the data extraction process.
 */
const init = async () => {
  try {
    // See: #1
    getHelpDialogue();

    // See: #2
    const uniqueSimulatorIdentifiers = await getFilteredSimulators(
      VARIABLES.targetSims,
      VARIABLES.completedSims,
      VARIABLES.problematicSims
    );

    // Check to see if the simulator list has anything to parse.
    // Otherwise we gracefully exit.
    if (uniqueSimulatorIdentifiers.length === 0) {
      console.log('[i] There are no new target simulators');
      console.log('    ↳ Check that the list is either (a) not empty,');
      console.log('      or (b) the items do not already exist in the');
      console.log('      completed or problematic lists.');
      process.exit(0);
    }

    // See: #4
    const parsedDatabaseOfModels = await convertCSVtoJson(VARIABLES.deviceCsv);

    // See: #5
    const targetSimulatorObjectData = getSimulatorObjectData(
      uniqueSimulatorIdentifiers,
      parsedDatabaseOfModels
    );

    // See: #6
    const buildSettings = getAppBuildPath(
      VARIABLES.projectPath,
      VARIABLES.schemeName
    );

    // See: #7
    const getSimulatorData = await getDataFromSimulators(
      buildSettings,
      targetSimulatorObjectData
    );

    // See: #8
    const lastRunData = await getLastRunData(
      VARIABLES.mergedOutputFilePath
    );
    
    // We use this to check if there is the last run JSON to update that.
    // Otherwise if there isn't, we assume it is first run, and return the CSV -> JSON.
    let data;
    if (lastRunData && !isEmptyObject(lastRunData)) {
      data = lastRunData;
    } else {
      data = parsedDatabaseOfModels;
    }

    // See: #9
    const result = mergeData(
      data,
      getSimulatorData
    );

    // See: #10
    await saveData(
      VARIABLES.mergedOutputFilePath,
      VARIABLES.bezelKitResources,
      result
    );

    // See: #11
    //await clearFile(VARIABLES.targetSims);

    // See: #12
    await sortFiles([
      VARIABLES.completedSims,
      VARIABLES.problematicSims
    ]);

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('[x] ERROR: An error occurred during data extraction process.');
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};


/**
 * 1. Displays a help message and exits the script if the help flag is provided.
 */
const getHelpDialogue = () => {
  if (ARGS.help || ARGS.h) {
    console.log(
      "---------------------------------------------------\n"    +
      "--               BezelKit Generator              --\n"    +
      "---------------------------------------------------\n"    +
      "\n"                                                       +
      "Usage: node index.js [options]\n\n"                       +
      "Options:\n"                                               +
      "  --deviceCsv\n\tThe CSV file with the Apple model and identifiers\n" +
      "  --targetSims\n\tA text file with the identifiers you wish to get data from\n" +
      "  --completedSims\n\tA text file of past, completed identifiers\n" +
      "  --problematicSims\n\tA text file of error identifiers - either not found or error in creation or use\n" +
      "  --projectPath\n\tPath to the Xcode project to fetch bezel sizes\n" +
      "  --schemeName\n\tSceheme for the aboce Xcode project\n" +
      "  --bundleID\n\tThe app bundle ID of the above project for easy install\n" +
      "  --mergedOutputFilePath\n\tFile location to output local JSON file with data\n" +
      "  --bezelKitResources\n\tThe JSON file used in the Package\n" +
      "  --debug\n\tLog files to output or supress them\n" +
      "  --help\n\tDisplay this screen\n\n" +
      "Chances are you won't need to override any of these, but they're built in for growth or custom setups. Mainly would be good if you need use your own CSV file or custom list of device identifiers. Most beneficial section is the projectPath, schemeName, and bundleID where you can use that logic for your own app.\n\n"
    );
    process.exit(0);
  }
};

/**
 * 2. Filters out completed and problematic simulators from the target simulators list.
 *
 * @param {string} targetList - The path to the target simulators list file.
 * @param {string} completedList - The path to the completed simulators list file.
 * @param {string} problematicList - The path to the problematic simulators list file.
 * @returns {Promise<string[]>} A Promise that resolves with an array of unique simulator identifiers that are not completed or problematic.
 */
const getFilteredSimulators = async (targetList, completedList, problematicList) => {
  // Get unique lines from the respective files
  const targetUnique = await getUniqueLinesFromFile(targetList);
  const completedUnique = await getUniqueLinesFromFile(completedList);
  const problematicUnique = await getUniqueLinesFromFile(problematicList);

  // Filter and return unique simulator identifiers not completed or problematic
  return [...targetUnique].filter(
    simulator => (
      !completedUnique.has(simulator) &&
      !problematicUnique.has(simulator)
    )
  );
};

/**
 * 4. Converts CSV data into a structured JSON format.
 *
 * @param {string} csvFilePath - The path to the CSV file.
 * @returns {Promise<Object>} A Promise that resolves with the parsed JSON data.
 */
const convertCSVtoJson = async (csvFilePath) => {
  // Create a read stream for the CSV file
  const fileStream = fs.createReadStream(csvFilePath);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({ input: fileStream, crlfDelay: Infinity });

  // Define device types and initialize output structures
  const deviceTypes = [
    { type: 'iPod', prefix: 'iPod' },
    { type: 'iPhone', prefix: 'iPhone' },
    { type: 'iPad', prefix: 'iPad' },
    { type: 'Watch', prefix: 'Watch' },
  ];
  const output = {};
  const deviceDicts = {};
  deviceTypes.forEach(device => {
    output[device.type] = [];
    deviceDicts[device.type] = {};
  });

  // Function to determine device type based on identifier
  const getDeviceType = identifier => {
    if (!identifier) return null;
    for (const device of deviceTypes) {
      if (identifier.startsWith(device.prefix)) return device.type;
    }
    return null;
  };

  // Parse each line of the CSV and populate the output structure
  for await (const line of rl) {
    const regex = /(?:[^,"]+|"[^"]*")+/g;
    const fields = [];
    let match;
    while ((match = regex.exec(line)) !== null) {
      fields.push(match[0].replace(/"/g, '').trim());
    }

    const [device, identifier] = fields;
    const deviceType = getDeviceType(identifier);

    if (deviceType) {
      if (!deviceDicts[deviceType][device]) {
        const newDevice = {
          device,
          identifiers: [identifier],
          bezel: 0.00
        };

        deviceDicts[deviceType][device] = newDevice;
        output[deviceType].push(newDevice);
      } else {
        deviceDicts[deviceType][device].identifiers.push(identifier);
      }
    }
  }

  return output;
};

/**
 * 5a. Finds the device name in the given database based on its identifier.
 *
 * @param {string} identifier - The device identifier to search for.
 * @param {Object} database - The database containing device information.
 * @returns {string|null} The device name if found, or null if not found.
 */
const findDeviceInDatabase = (identifier, database) => {
  for (const category in database) {
    for (const device of database[category]) {
      if (device.identifiers.includes(identifier)) {
        return device.device;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

/**
 * 5b. Finds the installed simulator with the given device name.
 *
 * @param {string} deviceName - The device name to search for.
 * @returns {Object|null} The installed simulator object if found, or null if not found.
 */
const findInstalledSimulator = (deviceName) => {
  const installedSimulators = getInstalledSimulators();
  for (const runtime in installedSimulators) {
    for (const device of installedSimulators[runtime]) {
      if (device.name === deviceName) {
        return device;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

/**
 * 5c. Finds the supported runtime for the given device name.
 *
 * @param {string} deviceName - The device name to search for.
 * @returns {Object|null} An object with deviceType and runtime identifiers if found, or null if not found.
 */
const findSupportedRuntime = (deviceName) => {
  const installedRuntimes = getInstalledRuntimes();
  for (const runtime of installedRuntimes) {
    for (const deviceType of runtime.supportedDeviceTypes) {
      if (deviceType.name === deviceName) {
        return {
          deviceType: deviceType.identifier,
          runtime: runtime.identifier,
        };
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

/**
 * 5d. Finds the state of a simulator based on its UDID.
 *
 * @param {string} udid - The UDID of the simulator to search for.
 * @returns {string|null} The state of the simulator if found, or null if not found.
 */
const findSimulatorState = (udid) => {
  const installedSimulators = getInstalledSimulators();
  for (const runtime in installedSimulators) {
    for (const device of installedSimulators[runtime]) {
      if (device.udid === udid) {
        return device.state;
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
};

/**
 * 5e. Installs a simulator with the provided details.
 *
 * @param {Object} options - The options for simulator installation (name, deviceType, runtime).
 * @returns {string|null} The UDID of the installed simulator if successful, or null if there's an error.
 */
const installSimulator = ({ name, deviceType, runtime }) => {
  try {
    const command = `xcrun simctl create "${name}" "${deviceType}" "${runtime}"`;
    const result = execSync(command).toString();
    return result.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('[x] ERROR: installing simulator');
    console.error(`    ↳ Message: ${error.message}`);
    return null;
  }
};

/**
 * 5f. Processes a simulator identifier and performs necessary actions based on its state.
 *
 * @param {string} identifier - The simulator identifier to process.
 * @param {Object} database - The database containing device information.
 * @returns {Object|null} An object with simulator details if successfully processed, or null if there's an issue.
 */
const processIdentifier = (identifier, database) => {
  // Find the device name in the database using the identifier
  const deviceName = findDeviceInDatabase(identifier, database);

  if (!deviceName) {
    // Move the identifier to problematic-list file and return
    moveData(
      identifier,
      VARIABLES.targetSims,
      VARIABLES.problematicSims
    );
    return null;
  }

  // Check if the device is already installed
  const installedDevice = findInstalledSimulator(deviceName);
  if (installedDevice) {
    return {
      udid: installedDevice.udid,
      deviceName: installedDevice.name,
      identifier: identifier,
      state: installedDevice.state
    };
  }

  // Find a supported runtime for the device
  const supportedRuntime = findSupportedRuntime(deviceName);
  if (!supportedRuntime) {
    console.warn(`[!] WARN: no supported runtime found for device: ${deviceName}`);
    console.warn('    ↳ Moving the identifier to problematic-list file');
    moveData(
      identifier,
      VARIABLES.targetSims,
      VARIABLES.problematicSims
    );
    return null;
  }

  // Install the simulator
  const udid = installSimulator({ ...supportedRuntime, name: deviceName });
  if (!udid) {
    console.warn(`[!] WARN: failed to install simulator for device: ${deviceName}`);
    console.warn('    ↳ Moving the identifier to problematic-list file');
    moveData(
      identifier,
      VARIABLES.targetSims,
      VARIABLES.problematicSims
    );
    return null;
  }

  // Find the state of the installed simulator
  const state = findSimulatorState(udid);

  // Move the identifier to completed-list file
  console.warn(`[i] INFO: moving identifier to completed-list file"`);
  console.warn('    ↳ Identifier: ${identifier}');
  console.warn('    ↳ Destination: ${VARIABLES.completedSims}');
  moveData(
    identifier,
    VARIABLES.targetSims,
    VARIABLES.completedSims
  );

  return { udid, deviceName, identifier, state };
};

/**
 * 5g. Processes a list of simulator identifiers and returns simulator data for successful ones.
 *
 * @param {string[]} identifiers - An array of simulator identifiers to process.
 * @param {Object} database - The database containing device information.
 * @returns {Object[]} An array of simulator data objects for successful identifiers.
 */
const getSimulatorObjectData = (identifiers, database) => {
  const results = [];
  const failedIdentifiers = [];

  for (const identifier of identifiers) {
    const result = processIdentifier(identifier, database);
    if (result) {
      results.push(result);
    } else {
      failedIdentifiers.push(identifier);
    }
  }

  if (failedIdentifiers.length) {
    console.warn('[!] WARN: Some identifiers were not found');
    console.warn(`    ↳ Identifiers: ${failedIdentifiers}`);
  }

  return results;
};

/**
 * 6. Builds the project, retrieves build settings, and returns the app build path.
 *
 * @param {string} projectPath - The path to the Xcode project file.
 * @param {string} projectScheme - The name of the Xcode project scheme.
 * @returns {string} The path to the built app.
 */
const getAppBuildPath = (projectPath, projectScheme) => {

  // Build the project and hide any lines with a warning
  executeCommand(`xcodebuild -project "${projectPath}" -scheme "${projectScheme}" -destination 'generic/platform=iOS Simulator' clean build 2>&1 | grep -v warning`);

  // Get the build settings
  const buildSettings = executeCommand(`xcodebuild -project "${projectPath}" -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Debug -showBuildSettings`);

  // Build the derived data path
  const builtProductsDirectory = getSettingValue(buildSettings, "BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR");
  const fullProductName = getSettingValue(buildSettings, "FULL_PRODUCT_NAME");

  return `${builtProductsDirectory}/${fullProductName}`;
};

/**
 * 7. Executes a series of steps on a list of simulators to extract data from the app.
 *
 * @param {string} appBuildPath - The path to the built app.
 * @param {Object[]} simulators - An array of simulator objects to process.
 * @returns {Promise<Object[]>} A Promise that resolves with an array of data from the simulators.
 */
const getDataFromSimulators = async (appBuildPath, simulators) => {
  const allSimulatorData = [];
  const bundleID = VARIABLES.bundleID;

  for (const simulator of simulators) {

    console.log(`[i] Start work on simulator: ${simulator.deviceName}`);
    console.log(`    ↳ Name: ${simulator.deviceName}`);
    console.log(`    ↳ Identifier: ${simulator.identifier}`);
    console.log(`    ↳ UDID: ${simulator.udid}`);
    console.log(`    ↳ State: ${simulator.state}`);

    // Shutdown any open simulators if not already shut down
    if (simulator.state !== 'Shutdown') {
      console.log('  - Simulator is not shut down. Closing...');
      executeCommand(`xcrun simctl shutdown "${simulator.udid}"`);
      console.log('  - Simulator is shut down');
    }

    // Boot the simulator
    console.log('  - Booting the simulator for testing');
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl boot '${simulator.udid}'`);

    // Install the desired app
    console.log(`  - Installing the app with bundle ID: ${bundleID}`);
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl install '${simulator.udid}' "${appBuildPath}"`);

    // Launch the app
    console.log(`  - Launching the app with bundle ID: ${bundleID}`);
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl launch '${simulator.udid}' '${bundleID}'`);

    // Wait for 5 seconds
    await delay(5000);

    // Get app container path and retrieve simulator data
    const appContainerPath = executeCommand(`xcrun simctl get_app_container '${simulator.udid}' '${bundleID}' data`).trim();
    const outputFilePath = `${appContainerPath}/Documents/output.txt`;
    const simulatorOutputContent = fs.readFileSync(outputFilePath, 'utf8');
    const simulatorData = JSON.parse(simulatorOutputContent);

    // Build device data for the simulator
    const deviceData = {
      device: simulator.deviceName,
      identifiers: [simulatorData.identifiers],
      bezel: simulatorData.bezel
    };

    // Append device data to the array
    allSimulatorData.push(deviceData);

    // Wait for 5 seconds
    await delay(5000);

    // Close the app
    console.log(`  - Terminating the app with bundle ID: ${bundleID}`);
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl terminate '${simulator.udid}' "${bundleID}"`);

    // Delete the app
    console.log(`  - Deleting the app with bundle ID: ${bundleID}`);
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl uninstall "${simulator.udid}" "${bundleID}"`);

    // Shut the simulator down
    console.log(`  - Shutting down simulator`);
    executeCommand(`xcrun simctl shutdown "${simulator.udid}"`);

    console.log(`[i] Ended work on simulator: ${simulator.deviceName}\n`);
  };

  return allSimulatorData;
};

/**
 * 8. Gets and parses the previously run JSON data.
 * 
 * @param {string} dataFile - The file path to the JSON file
 * @returns {Object} The parsed JSON data.
 */
const getLastRunData = async (dataFile) => {
  const jsonData = await fsp.readFile(dataFile);
  return JSON.parse(jsonData);
};

/**
 * 9. Merges new data into the original device data using matching identifiers.
 *
 * @param {Object} original - The original device data object.
 * @param {Object[]} newData - An array of device data to merge into the original.
 * @returns {Object} The modified original device data with merged bezel values.
 */
const mergeData = (original, newData) => {
  for (const category in original) {
    if (original.hasOwnProperty(category)) {
      original[category] = original[category].map(device => {
        // Find a matching new device based on identifiers
        const matchingNewDevice = newData.find(newDevice =>
          device.identifiers.some(id => newDevice.identifiers.includes(id))
        );
        if (matchingNewDevice) {
          device.bezel = matchingNewDevice.bezel;
        }
        return device;
      });
    }
  }
  return original;
};

/**
 * 10. Asynchronously saves data into a JSON files: one uncompressed, the other compressed.
 *
 * @param {string} uncompressedFilePath - The base file path for the uncompressed JSON file.
 * @param {string} compressedFilePath - The base file path for the compressed JSON file.
 * @param {object} data - The data object to be saved in the files.
 *
 * @throws {Error} If there's an error writing to the files.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<void>} A promise that resolves when the files have been written.
 */
const saveData = async (uncompressedFilePath, compressedFilePath, data) => {
  await fsp.writeFile(
    uncompressedFilePath,
    JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
  );
  await fsp.writeFile(
    compressedFilePath,
    JSON.stringify(data, null, null)
  );
};

/**
 * 11. Asynchronously clears the content of a file.
 *
 * @param {string} filePath - The path to the file that needs to be cleared.
 *
 * @throws {Error} If there's an error writing to the file.
 *
 * @returns {Promise<void>} A promise that resolves when the file has been cleared.
 */
const clearFile = async (filePath) => {
  await fsp.writeFile(filePath, '', 'utf-8');
};

/**
 * 12. Asynchronously sorts the lines of multiple text files and writes the sorted content to new files.
 *
 * @param {string[]} filePaths - An array of paths to the text files that will be sorted.
 * @throws Will log an error if sorting of any file fails.
 */
const sortFiles = async (filePaths) => {
  for (const filePath of filePaths) {
    await sortFile(filePath);
  }
};


/**
 * Generates a configuration object containing variable values.
 * Uses command line arguments or defaults if arguments are not provided.
 *
 * @param {Object} ARGS - Command line arguments.
 * @returns {Object} A configuration object with variable values.
 */
const VARIABLES = ((ARGS) => ({
  deviceCsv: assignOrDefault(ARGS.deviceCsv, DEFAULTS.deviceCsv),
  targetSims: assignOrDefault(ARGS.targetSims, DEFAULTS.targetSims),
  completedSims: assignOrDefault(ARGS.completedSims, DEFAULTS.completedSims),
  problematicSims: assignOrDefault(ARGS.problematicSims, DEFAULTS.problematicSims),
  projectPath: assignOrDefault(ARGS.projectPath, DEFAULTS.projectPath),
  schemeName: assignOrDefault(ARGS.schemeName, DEFAULTS.schemeName),
  bundleID: assignOrDefault(ARGS.bundleID, DEFAULTS.bundleID),
  mergedOutputFilePath: assignOrDefault(ARGS.mergedOutputFilePath, DEFAULTS.mergedOutputFilePath),
  bezelKitResources: assignOrDefault(ARGS.bezelKitResources, DEFAULTS.bezelKitResources),
  debug: assignOrDefault(ARGS.debug, DEFAULTS.debug)
}))(ARGS);

// MARK: - Initialize the script
init();
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick review

- You have a lot of 'obvious' comments, I can understand why because of your background, but it's something you should address as you gain more experience

  - Comments like `// See: #10` win the cake ;)
  - When I read `const installSimulator` it seems you got tired of the extensive commenting, but now the code looks inconsistent, I would review the code to have sparser commenting everywhere
- Regex `replace(/[:.]/g, '-');` should always have a comment though ;)
- `getHumanReadableTimestamp` is very cool, I learned something
- I personally do not like visually the autodoc comments in `DEFAULTS`
- Consider chaining a little more

  this

  ```
  // Read the file into a string
  const data = await fsp.readFile(filePath, 'utf8');

  // Split the string into lines
  const lines = data.split('\n');

  // Sort the lines
  const sortedLines = lines.sort();

  // Join the sorted lines back into a string
  const sortedData = sortedLines.join('\n');
  ```

  could be

  ```
  // Read the file into a string and split into lines
  const lines = await fsp.readFile(filePath, 'utf8').split('\n');

  // Sort the lines and join back into 1 string
  const sortedLines = lines.sort().join('\n');
  ```

  or even

  ```
  // Read the file and sort all lines
  const lines = await fsp.readFile(filePath, 'utf8').split('\n').sort().join('\n');
  ```

  and

  ```
  const result = execSync(command).toString();
  return result.trim();
  ```

  should be

  ```
  return execSync(command).toString().trim();
  ```
- The code relies a lot on `null`. I would suggest that you can replace this everywhere with `undefined`, [and it will be better for it](https://2ality.com/2021/01/undefined-null-revisited.html). At the very least you could drop `return null;` because JS returns `undefined` by default.

All in all, this looks good. This looks like a great contribution to the iOS community.